# conditionally removing first two letter of every entry in a string in R

Tags: r, text, replace, str-replace, gsub

I have a vector with some codes. However, for an unknown reason, some of the code start with X# (# being a number 0-9). If my vector item does start with x#, I need to remove the first two letters.

Examples:

```r
codes <- c('x0fa319-432f39-4fre78', '23weq0-4fsf198-417203', 'x2431-5435-1242-qewf')
expectedResult <- c('fa319-432f39-4fre78', '23weq0-4fsf198-417203', '431-5435-1242-qewf')
```

I tried using `str_replace` and `gsub`, but I couldn't get it right:

```
gsub("X\\d", "", codes)
```

but this would remove the x# even if it was in the middle of the string.

Any ides?

Comment: You used capital `X` instead of `x` in `gsub()`. It will work if you change that. Can also use it as `^x\\d` to only match that pattern at the beginning if you expect it could potentially appear elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
codes <- c('x0fa319-432f39-4fre78', '23weq0-4fsf198-417203', 'x2431-5435-1242-qewf')
sub("^x\\d", "", codes, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/1R9UNX).

The `^x\d` pattern matches `x` and any digit at the start of a string.

`sub` replaces the first occurrence only.

`ignore.case=TRUE` enables case insensitive matching.